# How to snap to sibling element in Figma?

Tags: alignment, figma, snapping

In the case where you have two sibling elements, how do you snap the edges of one with the edges of the other? Is there some kind of "magnet" mode which you can enable to achieve this behavior, similar to how it works in other illustration software like Affinity Designer, Illustrator and Photoshop? To be completely clear, I am not looking for "snap-to-grid" functionality, but specifically snapping to other existing elements.

Desired behavior (illustrated with Affinity Designer):
[image: desired behavior]

Current behavior (Figma):
[image: figma]

Comment: Is Snap to Objects disabled?

Comment: @MG_ where would I find this "Snap to Objects" option?

Comment: Figma Main Menu (to the left of the Move tool) > Preferences > Snap to objects.

Comment: Yes, the snap to objects option is enabled. It does, however, not snap to objects as described above. @MG_

Comment: I don't know Figma at all- try grabbing the object from a corner point and move it rather than just anywhere on the object. In other vector software this helps with snapping to other objects.

Comment: can't reproduce the problem. I made a similar setup as yours (shape inside a group) the shape still snaps to any other object in the same Frame.

Comment: @CobieFisher same issue here, a year later. On Win 10.

Answer (score -1):

Objects are snap if they are in the same frame

[image]

Comment: Hi Roman, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate on what you mean exactly? What's a frame, and how does one make sure objects are in the same one? Screenshots usually help with this sort of thing. Thanks! Keep contributing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/112925)

Comment: Added a picture